# AWS Cognito - where in code should I process oAuth authorization code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have got one beginners questions. I am just starting with AWS Cognito User Pools and set oAuth "Authorization Code Grant" workflow succesfully - so now, after the login, I am **succesfully redirected and get the authorization code** in the url. The next step is to exchange it for the actual JWT token, but the problem is that I **miss some broader perspective** and dont know whats the best practice in this case. I know the javascript code to exchange the code for token, but I dont know where it should run.

Shall I use **Triggers** functionality in my user pools, tie Lambda function to some event (which one? "Post Authentication"?) and let this Lambda function exchange the code for token and save it as a session?

Or **shall I put all this functionality into the url** I redirect to after a successful login? Is there some best practice for this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question to ask is: "Now the user is authorized.. now what?"

The AWS services that you want to make available to your users will determine what type of authentication flow you need to use. Since your question is fairly broad.. I will give you the high level of two types of authentication flow.

**Federated Identities**:
You can configure [federated identities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html) to grant users AWS IAM credentials (AccessKey and AccessSecret). When you set up a Federated Identity Pool, you specify the identities that can receive IAM credentials (for example: Your cognito pool, google, any other openID provider) and the IAM policy which will grant access to specified resources. This [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html) will review how to do this in your application code.

**API Gateway Custom Authorizer** You can also configure a [Custom Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) with the source being your Cognito User Pool. This will allow you to make a request using the jwt `#id_token` received from authenticating against the user pool.

**Specific answers to questions:**

*Shall I use Triggers functionality in my user pools, tie Lambda function to some event (which one? "Post Authentication"?) and let this Lambda function exchange the code for token and save it as a session?* - Generally Triggers are used to store user data for analytics or server side processing. If you are using Cognito for authentication you don't need to use Lambda

*Or shall I put all this functionality into the url I redirect to after a successful login? Is there some best practice for this situation?* - I would recommend using a library such as [AWS Amplify](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) to manage [Authentication](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide) with Cognito.

Answer (score 1):

Most common approach I have seen with recommendation for code grant flow is the approach you mentioned,

> shall I put all this functionality into the url I redirect to after a
>   successful login

The advantage of this is that you can store the refresh token server side and use it to refresh the id_token before it expires (There are several places which states not to store the refresh token client side).

However, if you look at the implementation in [AWS AmplifyJS](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) library for Code Grant, it does this in client side storing the refresh token also in local storage and refreshes the id_token from client side using JavaScript.

So both approaches are there while using both in different projects, I feel the latter is easy to implement and maintain.